# In SQL Server , I want to separate string from '~'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem. There are `A~B~C~D` values in my table.

I want separate this string like 'A' and 'B~C'.

And I could separate 'A' using this function

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Item.Description, 0, CHARINDEX('~', Item.Description)) As Com
```

But after that, I can't separate 'B~C'.

Of course if I use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` a lot, I can separate.

But it is very complicated.

So I wonder if I can use other ways.

Thx very much for reading

Answer (score 5):

Here is a short SQL function that you can create in order to split your string:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(8000))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH splitter_cte AS (
      SELECT CHARINDEX(@sep, @s) as pos, 0 as lastPos
      UNION ALL
      SELECT CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, pos + 1), pos
      FROM splitter_cte
      WHERE pos > 0
    )
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, lastPos + 1,
                     case when pos = 0 then 80000
                     else pos - lastPos -1 end) as chunk
    FROM splitter_cte
  )
GO
```

And here is how you would use it:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Split('~', 'A~B~C~D')
```

OUTPUT:

```
chunk
-------------
A
B
C
D
```

Read more on how this [sql split function](http://stevestedman.com/2012/04/using-a-cte-to-split-a-string-into-rows/) works